# Angularjs $routeParams causing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using AngularJS v1.5.9 and use $routeParams I get the following errors on my chrome console over and over again.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at la (angular.js:10097)
    at p (angular.js:9492)
    at g (angular.js:8757)
    at angular.js:8637
    at Object.link (angular-route.js:1065)
    at angular.js:1259
    at la (angular.js:10095)
    at p (angular.js:9492)
    at g (angular.js:8757)
    at angular.js:8637

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.error (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:119:129)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:91:305
    at la (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:82:112)
    at p (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:67:274)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:59:252)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:58:394
    at Object.link (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.js:1065:7)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:16:71
    at la (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:82:90)
    at p (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js:67:274) <main ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed [this example](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) pretty closly.  Here is my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);  // TODO: 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap' 

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/static/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController as mainCtrl'

        })
        .when('/match/id/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'components/match/matchView.html',
            controller: 'matchController'
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('mainController', [function(){
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.test = 'testing mainController';
}]);

 app.controller('matchController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    // var matchCtrl = this;
    $scope.name = 'matchController';
    $scope.params = $routeParams;
 });
```

### UPDATE

The error occurs when I go to example.com/match/id/123.

When I place breakpoints in the chrome inspector I see that it just keeps going into the `matchController` over and over again, but I have no idea why?  When it stops on the break point, I can see that the $routeParams has the correct value.

The file structure is pretty simple, all the JS is in one file, app.js, as per above.  And I only have two routes configured so far. And two static templates for header, nav & footer, but the have no controllers.

Comment: can you give more info like when do you get error, file structure of the project, and when the error is logged? @Holy

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban, Just updated the question, thanks for checking it out

Comment: I just posted an answer which seems to be possible reason. @Holy

Comment: what kind of server are you running this on?  this behavior usually occurs if the server doesn't understand how to handle angular HTML5 Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra id from your route setting and see if it helps:

```
.when('/match/:id', {
     templateUrl: '/app/components/match/matchView.html',
     controller: 'matchController'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I didn't have the full `templateURL` path set

```
templateUrl: 'components/match/matchView.html',
```

to

```
templateUrl: '/app/components/match/matchView.html',
```